# Modifying package gbm of R

Tags: c++, r, memory-management

We are trying to experiment using the gbm package on a quite large dataset (~140 million rows) and we have ran into a problem with the memory requirements of R.

We have tried combining the packages 'gbm' and 'bigmemory' with no success and our next thought was to modify the C++ source code to draw data from a local database where we have stored our dataset.

So, we were wondering if there is a more appropriate or well-known practice in order to change the allocation inside the C++ code of gbm. Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Did you consider sampling?  This may be more of a methodological questions for CrossValidated / stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: In this initial step we would like to pass all these data. Thank you for the reference to stats.stackexchange.com , we will ask also there.

Comment: (+1) @Dirk Thanks for the suggestion. CV has bounced the question back here because the focus is on persuading `R` to allocate more RAM (or somehow make more efficient use of the RAM), not on any statistical issues.

Comment: I see. Well, the initial idea of using something like bigmemory is a good. One needs an external pointer to keep the memory "away from R", and big memory does that. Rcpp call help too via Rcpp::XPtr.

Comment: Just use bigmemory but try to split up the data in more accessible parts. I always split up my data when experiencing that problem.
so data = largedata(1:10) and so on data1 = largedata(10:20) maybe this is the only solution because the memory management of R is not that good. Good luck!

Comment: have you looked at the ff, ffbase and ETLUtils package in R. I was able to read in ido (txt) files and do some work with it. The ff package reads in ido, csv, txt files as ffdf data frames. From there you can use the functions in the ff and ffbase packages although it will take some getting used to. In the ETLUtils package there are a few functions I haven't tried that read in data from a database but it is worth looking into such as; read.dbi.ffdf and read.odbc.ffdf. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not familiar with the gbm package, but if it works on data frames or vectors of some kind you could use the [ff package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html).

Quote: The ff package provides data structures that are stored on disk but behave (almost) as if they were in RAM by transparently mapping only a section (pagesize) in main memory...

Answer (score 2):

On CRAN you can get an uncompiled version of each package where the C code is still in text files, here is the link to the package source of gbm: http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/gbm_1.6-3.2.tar.gz. Extract the package, change the C code and compile it yourself with the R CMD INSTALL command, then you can load the package in R with your changed code.

Comment: @Trifyllenia did this help any?